# Syslog-ng with Python 3.7 in Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, syslog-ng

I am using the following Dockerfile to create an image with Python 3.7.4 and Syslog-ng:

```
FROM python:3.7.4

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    gnupg2

RUN wget -qO - https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/laszlo_budai:/syslog-ng/Debian_9.0/Release.key | apt-key add -
RUN echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/laszlo_budai:/syslog-ng/Debian_9.0 ./' | tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list.d/syslog-ng-obs.list

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
    syslog-ng

COPY ./out.log /out.log
COPY ./syslog-ng.conf /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf

RUN find /usr/lib/ -name 'libjvm.so*' | xargs dirname | tee --append /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openjdk-libjvm.conf
RUN ldconfig

EXPOSE 514/udp
EXPOSE 601/tcp
EXPOSE 6514/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/syslog-ng", "-F"]
```

However, I want to use Python 3.7.4 in my syslog-ng.conf and syslog-ng is using Python 2.7.

How can I change to Python 3?

---

### Edit: Solution by [MrAnno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5112690/mranno)

Compile and configure with python3:

```
RUN cd /syslog && \
    ./configure --with-python=3 --enable-ssl --enable-systemd --enable-debug  && \
    make && make install

RUN ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (v3.22.1), all syslog-ng packages in the `home:/laszlo_budai:/syslog-ng` repository are compiled with Python 2. It can't be changed, you have to recompile syslog-ng from source with the `--with-python=3` configure flag specified.

Comment: I tried to build it from source, but when I execute "syslog-ng -F" but nothing happens. Only blank screen